# How to get a variable that comes from a service in angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have this create-movies component, that let me create a movie using a form.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-createMovie',
  templateUrl: './createMovie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./createMovie.component.css']
})

export class CreateMovieComponent{

   constructor(public moviesService:MoviesService) { }

  onMovieCreate(form:NgForm){
     const movie:Movie = {
      title:form.value.title,
      file:form.value.file,
      direction:form.value.direction,
      year:form.value.year,
      country:form.value.country,
      duration:form.value.duration,
      cast:{
          name1:form.value.name1,
          name2:form.value.name2
          }
      }
    
  this.moviesService.addMovie(movie)
}
}
```

and this service that do some stuff, namely, store the movies in an array that will be then used by other components

```
@Injectable ({providedIn:"root"})

export class MoviesService{


    private movies:Movie[] = [];
    private moviesUpdated = new Subject<Movie[]>();


    constructor() { }

    addMovie(movie:Movie){
      this.movies.push(movie)
      this.moviesUpdated.next([...this.movies]);
   }


  getMoviesUpdateListener() {
    return this.moviesUpdated.asObservable();
  }
```

And when I call the service from another component to show the movies created, this.movies (which is needed in HTML) is empty.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  moviesUpdated:Subscription;
  movies:Movie[]=[]; 
  
  
  constructor(public movieService: MoviesService){}
  

  ngOnInit(){
      this.moviesUpdated = this.movieService
          .getMoviesUpdateListener()
          .subscribe(
            (moviesReturned:Movie[]) => {
              this.movies=moviesReturned;
            }
      );

}
```

this.movies, inside  subscribe is populated, but outside, it is [].

The HTML file of the component that needs the movie array.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
      <div class="col-8">
      <form  #classifyMovies="ngForm" (submit)=classifyEmotion(classifyMovies)>
      <div>
        <label for="chooseMovie" name="movie">Choose a <code>movie</code> or series</label>
          <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]=movie name="movie">

          <option [value]="movie.title" *ngFor="let movie of movies">{{movie.title}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      <div>
        <label for="chooseEmotion" name="emotion">How did you <code>felt</code>?</label>
        <select class="form-control" ngModel #emotion="ngModel" name="emotion">
          <option [value]="emotion.emotion" *ngFor="let emotion of emotions">{{emotion.emotion}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-classify" type="submit">Classify Movie</button>
      </form>
      <br><br><br>


      </div>
<div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this.movies is [] outside meaning in template? have you set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Comment: That is how async data works. You can't straight up access the variable `this.movies` outside the subscription and expect to get the latest value from the observable. The component does not know when it'll get the new values. So any statements that depend on `this.movies` must be inside the subscription. Or in other words you need to subscribe where you need the data.

Comment: well, yeah, in the template I call movies and nothing appears, but if I do a console.log after the subscribe, it's also empty. what I get from Micheal's answer this is right. But I need to use this.movies in template. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Michael, but I need to use it in the template, and it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you are getting values for movies inside the subscription but not in the template?

If that is so, check whether the current or parent components have ChangeDetection Strategy in @Component().

Comment: How can I check that? Is it easy to do, if not I can search the web

Comment: Yeah it's easy, you just have to look for a line containing changeDetectionStrategy. From your code, it is not present in your component. Just look if you have parent components. Go though the logic flow, and also checking your app.routing.module.ts. You may get an idea if a parent component is present. Also share your your template code. Let's try

Answer (score 0):

Your component is creating before your subscription fires more than likely. Michael's comment is pretty spot on, your component needs to subscribe to the data before it can display it. You should post your html as well I have no idea what you are doing there, especially since that is where you want to display. Nonetheless, here is the best practice I've found for handling observables in HTML.

In your TS file that you want to display the data you create an observable:

```
movies$: Observable<any> = this.this.movieService.getMoviesUpdateListener()
```

In your HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="movies$ | async as movies>
//JUST FOR THE SAKE OF TESTING:
{{movies | json}}
</ng-container>
```

The HTML handles the asyncronous subscription without you having to do in your TS. Essentially you create an instance of an observable in your TS, then you use the format listed above in your HTML to subscribe to that observable

Comment: Thanks @garret, I've added the HTML.  When I change ```movies:Movie[]=[]; ``` with ```movies:Observable<any> = this.movieService.getMoviesUpdateListener()```I get this error :  ERROR in src/app/components/home/home.component.ts(31,15): error TS2740: Type 'Movie[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.

Comment: Hmm I was not able to get the async to work either, maybe it is due to how the observable is set in your service. I got it to work with a subscription setting a variable in your TS, it's not exactly what you have going but should give you a rough idea. Let me know if you have any questions.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vjpypj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

`moviesUpdated:Subscription = this.moviesObs$.subscribe(x => this.movies = x);`

Comment: Here's the stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vjpypj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

It worked, using BehaviorSubject instead of Subject

```
  private moviesUpdated = new BehaviorSubject<Movie[]>([]);
```

and implementing

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.moviesUpdated.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I believe because Behavior Subject saves the last value.